# PptxGenJS - Wait till Save is Finish then Run Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, pptxgenjs

I am using `PptxGenJS` and I want to run a function after I save my PowerPoint. I figured I could use the `.then(...)` method, because the library already uses `Promise`.

However when I do try something like this:

```
pptx.save('Sample Presentation').then(function(){
    alert('done saving');
});
```

The `.then(..)` block does not execute.

Is there some other way to get my script to wait till the save action has been fully completed?

Answer (score 0):

In 'PptxGenJS' documentation also they mentioned,

```
pptx.save('Sample Presentation', ()=> {
           //do your stuff here
         });
```

Comment: Thanks @Prasanth-S, but I was looking to run action after saving has been completed-- this runs as save dialog is still open. It seems like there is no way to do this without a nodeJS implementation.